# I need help building a loop in Excel-VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I have a block of data like below that I need to insert into a sheet with several thousand rows.

[image]

The first catch is that some of the block is already there but incomplete. This is best illustrated with examples.

[image]

In this case, I am missing rows for 7010 and 7020.

[image]

In this case, I am only missing 7010. It’s all random. I could override the existing block but the second catch is that I have data in the cells to the right so the obvious solution is to insert blank rows corresponding to the missing numbers.

Because I know the block always start with a 7, I started doing something like (the data is in column B)

```
If Left(Cells(Row, 2), 1) = 7 Then
If Cells(Row, 2) = 7005 Then
```

Then realized that’s a quagmire of nested if statements. And then it gets trickier because after I insert the necessary row, the cycle repeats XD so I thought maybe I use an array to store the incomplete block and compare it to the complete block then insert rows that way but that’s also a nightmare. This is all made worse because I have to loop through the entire sheet and do this wherever necessary. I can code so if anyone can just provide logic, that will suffice.

If it’s easier, I do not need to fill in the newly inserted rows. Meaning I can just leave it all blank like below. Let me know if this makes sense or need more info.

[image]

Comment: Don't ask why I am doing this. I know it's obtuse but I don't have a choice XD

Comment: Actually it is pretty simple :) `1` Loop through the first block and check if it is there or not in the 2nd block. `2` If it is not then simply add it to the end of the block `3` Sort the 2nd complete block based on column 1 in the end. The blank rows on the right of the numbers will be automatically created :)

Comment: Whoa Sid. The man that started my SO journey! I feel honored ^_^; That's not bad at all. Figure out what's missing, add it then worry about order last. Will try that...

Comment: Hmmm what's the best way to do step 1? Block 2 doesn't always start with 7005. This is still very tedious XD

Comment: You will have to loop through the first block and then either use `.Find` or `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf` to check for duplicates

Comment: There's multiple approaches from there. Best is to append missing number as soon as it's not found instead of keeping an array to store them? Then it's a pain to keep track when original block ends? Uhh, wanna code this for me =P

Comment: I might just do this manually XD 5000 lines, 200-300 blocks I need to fix... an hour at most. This will take me days to code ;_;

Comment: It's very simple. You have done more complex coding :) Perhaps [this](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) may get you started.

Comment: More complex yes but not as tedious XD On somewhat of a time crunch so no time to study find/findnext :/ It's funny. A human can still be quicker than machine for several thousand lines in SOME cases ^_^ Please post your first comment as answer so I can mark it as closed? Finally, thank you for dropping by <3 Learned so much from you and look forward to continue doing so!

Comment: I will do better than that. i will not completely answer your question yet i will post enough to get you SPRINTING!!!

Comment: Ah, but I bet I can do this quicker manually than you coding =P The logic here is rather cumbersome.. at least for me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is pretty simple :)

Let me give you a hint with code examples which will not directly answer your question but will get you started!

**Note**: I am using hardcoded range for demonstration purpose.

1. Loop through the first block and check if it is there or not in the 2nd block.

**Example**

```
Dim BlockA As Range, BlockB As Range
Dim aCell As Range

Set BlockA = Range("M1:M10")
Set BlockB = Range("A1:A100")

For Each aCell In BlockA
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(BlockB, aCell.Value) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Match Found for " & aCell.Value
    Else
        Debug.Print "Match Not Found for " & aCell.Value
    End If
Next
```

2. If it is not then simply add it to the end of the block

First find the last row using [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) and then simply increment it before writing to it.

**Example**

```
LastRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
'~~> aCell is the cell which is not there in the 2nd block
Range("A" & LastRow).Value = aCell.Value
```

3. Sort the 2nd complete block based on column 1 in the end. The blank rows on the right of the numbers will be automatically created :)

**Example**

Let's say your range is from `A1:F100` then you can use this for sorting

```
With Sheet1
    .Columns("A:F").Sort Key1:=.Range("A2"), _
                         Order1:=xlAscending, _
                         Header:=xlYes, _
                         OrderCustom:=1, _
                         MatchCase:=False, _
                         Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
                         DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
End With
```

Comment: Gah you beat me. Kind of. I apologize. I was not clear. There are 4743 rows while each blockB only ranges from 5 to 100ish. So I don't want the lastrow of the sheet but lastrow of the current block. The sheet is also already sorted so when I sort, I need to only sort the current block as well. Although I could do a mass sort with multiple criteria at the very end. Still +1 and will DEFINITELY do this next year!